# Desktop vs Web Vs Mobile - UX guidelines document

Tags: guidelines, best-practice

Am in the process of setting standard ux guidelines across the organization for various internal external applications. So just wondering, is there any common elements which I can consider ux best practices for these different platforms?

Comment: worked on a style guide recently. its best to start with the most basic element. Hope these resources will be useful for you

http://styleguides.io/examples.html

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/designing-style-guidelines-for-brands-and-websites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Scope

This is a big question.

Are you asking about guidelines for **methods**?

- For example, every project must conduct usability research and allow time to implement any U-test recommendations.

Are you asking about guidelines for design **patterns** and **layout**?

- For example, for example, the action button is always to the left of the **Cancel** button, not vice versa.

Are you asking about guidelines for **interaction** and **nonfunctional specifications**?

- For example, the system must respond  to a tap or click ideally before 0.2 seconds, and always within 0.4 seconds. The response can be to show wait feedback.

Are you asking about terminology guidelines specific to your industry?

- For example, do you use the word drillhole or borehole? Or do you localise/localize for each market?

Or guidelines about something else? Whatever your focus is …

#### Don't reinvent the wheel

Documenting standards and then keeping those documents up to date is a huge job. Having custom standards is also a common **source of conflict**. Professional UX practitioners all have their preferences—which they can justify—and getting a team to agree on one set of rules takes effort and usually requires a manager to impose one choice. Because there are winners and losers, people may tend to be passive-aggressive and "can't find" the guidelines, or say "they're out of date" (which is often true), then they won't follow the guidelines. If practitioners don't follow the guidelines, then *in effect you don't have guidelines*.

I recommend you adopt existing standards. Tell everyone to hold their nose—if they think it stinks—and follow the standard.

#### Barn raising

For those things that are unique to your organization, write your guidelines together. To do this, collect the topics that need a guideline, and then repeat these steps:

1. Once a week, sit the whole team in a room, with their laptops for an hour or 90 minutes.
2. Have each person pick a topic. Everyone writes quietly for a 20 minute spree. Set a timer.
3. At the break, people can present what they wrote, ask questions, take feedback. two minutes per topic.

Put the guidelines go into a central, easy-to-find location, such as a wiki. Allow each writer to add keywords and links that work for them. (This can be a 20-minute spree.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you interpret UX with different kinds of platforms. I feel, UX is UX, doesn't matter what you are delivering. I believe, figuring out user needs, task models, user testing and so on are all similar, nothing much difference its not depends on what platform you are following.

Yes, each project will have its unique challenges and based on requirements that changes too. There are various technologies available in which we can build hassle free applications.